# How does one create spacing between lines of CSS code in Visual Studio Code

Tags: css, visual-studio-code, sass

I'm relatively new to VS Code and this site. The code below was done using scss. I cant figure out why vs code does this. Can anyone tell me which setting is controlling this behavior?

I would like to be able to add space between lines of code like I've seen others do in videos. for example

**I see this.**

```css
.feature-box {
    background-color: rgba($color-white, .8);
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    padding: 2.5rem;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 3px;
    box-shadow: 0 1.5rem 4rem rgba($color-black, .15);
    transition: transform .2s;
    &__icon {
        font-size: 6rem;
        margin-bottom: .5rem;
        display: inline-block;
        background-image: linear-gradient( to right, $primary-color-light, $primary-color-dark);
        background-clip: text;
        -webkit-background-clip: text;
        color: transparent;
    }
    &:hover {
        transform: translateY(-1.5rem) scale(1.02);
    }
}
```

But would like to see this.

```css
.feature-box {
    background-color: rgba($color-white, .8);
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    padding: 2.5rem;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 3px;
    box-shadow: 0 1.5rem 4rem rgba($color-black, .15);
    transition: transform .2s;
    
    &__icon {
        font-size: 6rem;
        margin-bottom: .5rem;
        display: inline-block;
        background-image: linear-gradient( to right, $primary-color-light, $primary-color-dark);
        background-clip: text;
        -webkit-background-clip: text;
        color: transparent;
    }
    
    &:hover {
        transform: translateY(-1.5rem) scale(1.02);
    }
}
```

Any help would greatly appreciated
thanks

Comment: I don't get about what you're talking about. Do you want VS Code to automatically add newlines for you?

Comment: I think this might be the problem due to "prettier" extension installed in the VS code as it formats and indents the code as per it's own style often removing whitespaces and line breaks.

Comment: @Magiczne, I'm sure you can tell I'm new to all of this. I'm trying figure out how to keep the spaces, when I add a space between lines of code they get removed immediately.

Comment: @RitikaGupta, I'm not using Prettier but I am using JS-CSS-HTML Formatter. Do you know of a way to get around this behavior. thanks

Comment: @Zeus60 next time you should put that information right in the question, guessing what are you using is not good as you can use anything. I think I have solution to your problem, look at answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. So according to the documentation of the [JS-CSS-HTML formatter](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=lonefy.vscode-JS-CSS-HTML-formatter)

You need to access configuration of that plugin by pressing `F1` then choosing `Formatter config`.

Next you need to customize the config file in the `css` section.

```
"css": {
    "selectorSeparatorNewLine": true,
    "newline_between_rules": true
}
```

I would also recommend not to use this plugin and use
[Prettier](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=esbenp.prettier-vscode) which is still maintained in contrast to `JS-CSS-HTML formatter` which looks like it was abandoned 3 years ago

Comment: Thank you for the advice on my question and the help with my problem. Your solution appears to have corrected the issue. I'm Looking at prettier per your advice and I'll be making the switch.

Thanks Again